# DHCP Server not Send Offer

Tags: wireshark, dhcp, stm32f4

I am creating TCP IP Stack for ENC28J60 with STM32f microcontroller. Everyting is OK. Encapsulation is OK. The package that I send, see wire shark like this:

[image: Wire Shark ScreenShot]

But DHCP Offer Package are not sent by server. What is wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone need this solution ,

Solution is in RFC1531 page 31. Most important thing, DHCP communication timing and states.

Encapsulation does not enough itself. By the way i saw DHCP Discover and Request message in wireshark. But package came to MCU .